# How to quickly change between arm64 or x86 architecture in M1/M2 Mac terminals?

Tags: macos

I have a M1 Macbook and I need to constantly change between x86 and arm64 architectures (thanks tensorflow and pytorch...). How do I do that?

Tried to install different python versions, no success.

Answer (score 19):

Add these lines to your `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
# Switch terminal architecture type:
alias x86="$env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh ---login"
alias arm="$env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh ---login"
```

This will allow you to quickly change architecture runtimes in your processor between arm64 (native) and i386 (rosetta), like this:

```bash
Last login: Wed Apr  5 10:23:46 on ttys000
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ % arch
i386
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ % arm
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ % arch
arm64
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ % x86
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ % arch
i386
(base) mtournier@ip-10-19-30-214 ~ %
```

Comment: Why `--login` is needed here? Also, note that after `x86` one can just `Ctrl+D` to exit the inner shell and return to the (default) arm64 one.

Comment: Also, I noticed you answered your own question, so thanks for sharing! +1